Challenging Projects Every <Roboticist> Should Try?
Note: Apologies if this isn't the right place to be asking this question. I'm not entirely sure!
TL;DR:
What challenging robotics projects offer the most "bang for your buck" in terms of maximizing learning for the time invested?
I recently came across this article and found the premise really intriguing! As a robotics student in uni (as opposed to a pure software engineer), I was curious if anyone with a more robotics-focused background could recommend similar projects that are challenging but provide substantial learning. In other words, which projects helped you develop into skilled robotics engineers, and why those projects in particular?
I understand that different roboticists will gravitate toward projects based on their specific interests or specializations. However, I believe there are core, fundamental skills that all good roboticists should develop, regardless of their specialty (At least to become good, well rounded robotics engineers). That's the kind of stuff I'm thinking about with this question.
I’m currently trying to progress from an intermediate to a more advanced level. At this point, I feel confident using certain tools but lack a deeper understanding of what’s happening under the hood. I’m hoping this discussion will inspire me and provide some direction on where to go next.

Welcome to Robotics willnatsan, but I'm afraid that Life Questions are off-topic. Choosing how to spend your time (books to read, classes to take, projects to construct, career to pursue etc.) may be difficult, but it's specific to you, so unlikely to help future visitors. Questions like this are welcome in [chat] when you have the privilege. We prefer practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face, see [ask] & [about].

My list of "most robotics learning for the investment":

build a physical robot, hardware, controller, SBC, ROS 2 drivers, LIDAR, URDF and Gazebo SDF, documentation and tutorials for autonomous wander, map, and navigate behaviors, with git release

add find_dock/docking/charging/battery_management/safety_shutdown hardware and ROS 2 behaviors to the robot that provide 24/7 autonomy for 30 days without a safety shutdown or human intervention

add stereo depth camera, ROS 2 driver, vSLAM integrated wander, map, and navigate behaviors

add "find interesting - unknown object and collect image data set" behavior, with off-board auto or human-assisted classification/identification and rebuild depth camera object recognition model with transfer learning with interesting object no longer "unknown"  (with daily report of objects "discovered, learned")



Let me add some opinionated support. To be sure, there are plenty of software specialties in robotics -- control theory, inverse kinematics, sensor fusion, path planning, etc. But as long as that's all trapped behind the glass of your monitor, it's not robotics, it's video games! Every roboticist needs to step away from the simulators from time to time. Build or work with a real, physical robot, embodied in the real world and interoperating with it. Even a limited degree of autonomy makes the difference between a robot and a remote-control toy.
